# Storing all selected check box values in one variable?

Tags: php

I came up here with little silly question i have retrieved all selected values from check boxes and store the values in database but i want to store all the selected values from check box to a single variable like i want to bind all the value and than want to store it in single database column.here is my little effort.

```
<?php

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("checkboxes",$con);
if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))
{
$checkbox1 = $_POST['chk1'];
$i=0;
$user="admin";
$store;
while($i<sizeof($checkbox1)) {
    echo $checkbox1[$i];
$query="INSERT INTO `speciman`(`type`, `user`) VALUES ('".$checkbox1[$i]."','".$user."')";
mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');
$store=$checkbox1[$i];
$i++;
}

echo '<br/>';
echo "Record is inserted.";
}

else
{

}
?>
```

And the form is here.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" value="blood">blood<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" value="bone">bone<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" value="urine">urine<br />

<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Use `array()` with `foreach`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP function  [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) , which make array to string. To select back , use [unserialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

For example:

```
$data = array(
        '1' => 'value1',
        '2' => 'value2',
        '3' => 'value3',
        '4' => 'value4'
        );                   
$newstring = serialize( $data );

/* This will return:
@
@    a:4:{i:1;s:6:"value1";i:2;s:6:"value2";i:3;s:6:"value3";i:4;s:6:"value4";}
@
*/       

@mysql_query("INSERT INTO `example` (`id`, `data`) VALUES('', $newstring)") or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$store = array(); // initialize $store variable as array
// then loop through the checkboxes and store the values in $store

// you have already written the loop... so now you have the values in $store and it is an array

// then use implode to convert the array to a string
$comma_separated = implode(",", $store);
// http://in1.php.net/function.implode <- implode doc reference
// to get back the values from imploded data, use explode http://in3.php.net/explode
```